# how to communicate containers running in same machine using the host machine ip address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two containers say container1 and container2 running in same machine. I know i can communicate between both the container using link alias option. I have a scenario where i want to communicate between 2 containers using the IP address of the host machine. I have a property file in container1 where i need to provide the ip address of the container2 (Here i have to provide the ip address and not hostname of container). Everytime when i restart the container, the container ip gets changed. so is there any way to map the ip address of the host machine to link between container ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this doc which describes how to create [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) and assign IP address and range to docker container. In case of lack of time use commands below:

```
docker network create --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 docnet0

docker run --net docnet0 --ip 192.168.0.10 -it "your_docker_image" bash
```

Comment: thanks @FaigB. i have a small doubt. both the containers need to communicate each other using the ip address. docker run does not allow me to use the same ip address. Do i need to provide a two different ip address for docker run command ?

Comment: Yes and using provided IPs you'll be able to enable communication between containers.

Comment: thanks a lot. So passing the ip address in --ip does not need to be the ip of the host machine rite ?

Comment: To prevent this just use different subnet which differs IP address range.